# How to remove specific elements from a JQuery object which is not yet added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a JQuery object which contains elements already being in the DOM, the remove function will properly remove them from it.

However, I would like to remove specific elements which are not yet added to the DOM, only existing in a JQuery object, like the following:

```
var $div = $("<div><span class='sample'></span></div>");
$div.remove(".sample");
console.log($div.html()); // prints out the original HTML, inner span is not removed
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, you just never can say safely that you know jQuery :) I'm gonna accept the most descriptive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the selector to `remove()` then the selector will be applied to the passes set of elements in your case `$div` which does not contain the `sample` element, it is a descendant of the elements referred by `$div`. So you need to use .find() to find the element and remove it

```js
var $div = $("<div><span class='sample'></span>some content</div>");
$div.find(".sample").remove();
$('#result').text($div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The $div holds the jquery object and they treated as a jquery object.

```
var $div = $("<div><span class='sample'>4334</span></div>");
$div.find(".sample").remove();
console.log($div.html());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zdgyer3/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `$div` would holds the object of the wrapper div element, so by using it, you could select its descendant by using `.find(selector)` function and after that remove it by `.remove()`

Try,

```js
 var $div = $("<div><span class='sample'></span>hai</div>");
 $div.find('.sample').remove();
 alert($div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny I thought it in a different way, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $div = $("<div>outside of sample <span class='sample'>inside of sample</span></div>");
$div.find(".sample").remove();
alert($div.html());
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/3p0zsa8h/